# Empty Array on running Java on PHP

Tags: java, php, exec

I have a java program in a .jar file, which I need to run through PHP. I have to send in 3 arguments (all 3 of them are strings, the first being a pretty big one), and receive an output after the execution.

I am using XAMPP and Symfony on Windows 10 for the whole project, although I doubt it's integral to the problem.

I have tried a few possibilities

At first I've tried:

```
exec("java -jar 'D:\Path\To\File\src\Service\Java\JavaFile.jar' ". $argument1 ." ". $argument2 ." ". $argument3. " 'package.Main'", $output, $errorcode)
```

Which didn't give me any result after var_dump/print_r/echo the *$output*

After that I went through a bunch of options (all listed below) while still not getting any output  - mostly I received an empty array.

```
exec("java -jar 'D:\Path\To\File\src\Service\Java\JavaFile.jar' \"". $argument1 ."\" \"". $argument2 ."\" \"". $argument3. "\" 'package.Main'  2>&1", $output, $errorcode)
```

```
exec("java -jar 'D:\Path\To\File\src\Service\Java\JavaFile.jar' '". $argument1 ."' '". $argument2 ."' '". $argument3. "' 'package.Main' 2>&1", $output, $errorcode)
```

```
$output = shell_exec("java -jar 'D:\Path\To\File\src\Service\Java\JavaFile.jar' '". $argument1 ."' '". $argument2 ."' '". $argument3. "' 'package.Main' 2>&1")
```

**This one however gave me a different output:**

I simply didn't send the arguments

```
$output = shell_exec("java -jar 'D:\Path\To\File\src\Service\Java\JavaFile.jar' 'package.Main' 2>&1")
```

**Unable to access jarfile**

Nothing I've found on the internet had helped. Answering some questions that might appear at first:

- yes, the jar does run properly in CLI
- yes, I can run basic commands through exec() and shell_exec() receiving an output
- yes, I did restart the server multiple times and it had no effect on the result
- yes, the .jar file is there
- the .jar file NEVER gives empty output based on the code

I am hoping for some help as this is a really important part for the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After over a week of fighting with this, I've managed to fix my problem.

## **This might not be avaliable solution for you.**

**My service will be running on Linux Server so this solution was avaliable for me.**

---

I've gotten in contact with a colleague of mine who is far more experienced with PHP than me. It took us about a week to come with conclusion that I need to **change the environment** from Windows to Linux.

To avoid installing a new OS on my device, the colleague proposed using [Docker](https://www.docker.com).
After few hours of work and following a two part tutorial ([part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITOnpzkzlYM) [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcU5XwlEeRU)) on how to setup PHP envoirnment in Docker (with Symfony, Mysql and Nginx) I managed to make it work.

I installed Java **inside php container** (an important part that caused me lots of confusion and problems), made sure that the paths to all the files are correct and that the *.jar file* has all the permissions. After that the *exec function* worked swimingly giving me the expected output.

Additionally, I've saved the first argument (which was a really long string) into a file and I've passed the path to the file as the argument instead. **Mind that I did that before I switched to Docker, so it might've worked with big strings after all.**

---

**TLDR;**

- switch to Linux (fe. Debian) - optionally using VM if you have to (fe. Docker)
- install Java next to PHP so they can communicate
- make sure all the paths are valid
- make sure the .jar file has all the required permissions (chmod)